# HaProxy use different backend based on path

Tags: haproxy, consul

I am using consul template with haproxy and trying to route to different backend based on url path. I tried to use acl but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my haproxy.cfg

```
defaults
   mode http

frontend stats
   bind *:1936
   stats uri /
   stats show-legends
   no log

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   default_backend emailHandler
   acl emailservice path_beg /email
   use_backend emailHandler if emailservice

backend emailHandler
    balance roundrobin
    server-template emailhandler-api 10 _emailhandler-api._tcp.service.consul resolvers consul resolve-opts allow-dup-ip resolve-prefer ipv4 check

resolvers consul
    nameserver consul 127.0.0.1:8600
    accepted_payload_size 8192
    hold valid 5s
```

When I try to visit http://localhost/email, I get 404. When I remove acl, my service works on http://localhost

I will be registering lot more service with consul and I want to use just one common entrypoint with different url paths for different service.
Can someone please help me figure this out?